# How to create Java mixins: @Slf4j

Tags: java, interface, mixins

I'm trying to create a Java mixin and use the `@Slf4j` annotation. However intellij shows an error `@Slf4j is only legal for classes and enums`.

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public interface Foo {
    default void foo() {
        log.info("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the logger to be associated with the class that uses the mixin, or with the interface?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough about this to have a preference. Either way is fine.

Comment: @nanotek you could accept an answer if it helped you to solve your question. Also, it helps other users understand which answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use logging for the interface you could use a constant:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public interface Foo {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

    default void foo() {
        log.info("Hello from Foo");
    }
}
```

If will have some implementation for this interface and you could overwrite a logger:

```
public class Bar implements Foo {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bar.class);

    public void bar() {
        log.info("Hello from Bar");
    }
}
```

With Lombok it could be done even simpler:

```
@Slf4j
class Bar implements Foo {
    public void bar() {
        log.info("Hello from Bar");
    }
}
```

Demo code:

```
public class LoggerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.foo();
        bar.bar();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
20:40:48.010 [main] INFO demo.Foo - Hello from Foo 
20:40:48.014 [main] INFO demo.Bar - Hello from Bar
```

Comment: *"you could overwrite a logger"* It doesn't work. `foo()` will always use the logger declared in the interface.

Comment: Have you tried to execute it?

Comment: @Olivier I checked it - and it works fine. The answer is updated a little bit with a demo example and output.

Comment: As I understand the question, the logger should be associated with the class, not the interface (because the OP is trying to create a mixin). The OP should clarify that.

Comment: From my point of view it is clear he wants to use a lover at interface. @Slf4j is available only for classes and enums. So main question is how to use logging for the interface as well.

Comment: @Olivier in my bounty I state that I'm not trying to be pedantic about an answer. I also state that I'm new to mixins. I've also not used them in other languages. I'm not sure what a mixin 'should' be. Maybe I'm wrong, but it feels like interfaces are no longer interfaces. Before this question I didn't know they could have inner classes, variables, or functions. IMO seems like they should have added multi inheritance to abstract classes (but probably couldn't). If you have something that explains why mixins shouldn't do this I'd love to read, but ATM I'm not sure what would be wrong about this

Comment: @nanotek updated the answer with Lombok example.

Comment: @catch23 Sorry about that, I thought by accepting the bounty it would auto accept the answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve the issue is to pass the logger to the `foo()` method:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public interface Foo {
    default void foo(Logger log) {
        log.info("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Then use the `@Slf4j` annotation on classes that implement `Foo`:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class Bar implements Foo {
    public void bar() {
        foo(log);
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. If you do it you will have the following log message: `20:51:18.227 [main] INFO Bar - Hello world`. Instead of logging where precisely is code executed (***Foo interface***), you will log the information where the log instance was initialized (***Bar class***).

Comment: @catch23 This is intended behavior. The OP said they wanted to implement the concept of mixin, so the logger should be associated with the class, not the interface (which is just a technical detail used to implement the mixin). At least this is how I understand the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a `getLogger` method to the interface and require the implementations to implement that method. Then the interface can call that method.

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public interface Foo {

    Logger getLogger();

    default void foo() {
        getLogger().info("Hello world");
    }
}

@Slf4j
public class Bar implements Foo {

    public void bar() {
        foo();
    }

    @Override
    public Logger getLogger() {
        return log;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create an inner class with a static `getLogger` method.

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public interface Foo {

    @Slf4j
    class Log {
        public static Logger getLogger() {
            return log;
        }
    }

    default void foo() {
        Log.getLogger().info("Hello world");
    }
}
```